# Can I display disassembly code along with symbols from the .bss section only?

Tags: avr-gcc, objdump

I'd like `avr-objdump` to show the disassembled code from an `avr-elf` binary file and also include symbols but only those from the `.bss` section, like this:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
00800100 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
00800102 u     O .bss   00000001 cqueue<drv::uart0>::ptr
00800101 u     O .bss   00000001 cqueue<drv::uart1>::ptr
...

00000000 <__vectors>:
   0:       78 c0           rjmp    .+240           ; 0xf2 <__ctors_end>
   4:       b2 c0           rjmp    .+356           ; 0x16a <__bad_interrupt>
   8:       b0 c0           rjmp    .+352           ; 0x16a <__bad_interrupt>
   c:       ae c0           rjmp    .+348           ; 0x16a <__bad_interrupt>
  10:       ac c0           rjmp    .+344           ; 0x16a <__bad_interrupt>
  14:       aa c0           rjmp    .+340           ; 0x16a <__bad_interrupt>
  18:       a8 c0           rjmp    .+336           ; 0x16a <__bad_interrupt>
  1c:       a6 c0           rjmp    .+332           ; 0x16a <__bad_interrupt>
  20:       a4 c0           rjmp    .+328           ; 0x16a <__bad_interrupt>
  24:       a2 c0           rjmp    .+324           ; 0x16a <__bad_interrupt>
```

...

Can it be done?

So far all my attempts have leaded to either showing the `.bss` section but no disassembly at all or show everything, code and all symbols from all sections...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your shell, you can just call `avr-objdump` twice to give a single integrated output:

```
(avr-objdump <symbols-from-bss>; avr-objdump <disassembly>)
```

Comment: Ah, I suspected something like that as I didn't spot any parameter that would do. Thanks :-).